# Passing parameters to REST web-service

Tags: java, rest, web-services, parameters

I'm dealing with the problem with passing parameteres to web-service.

I have created web-service which works OK for the case fromLanguage = "eng"

But, when I test service through Glassfish console and send fromLanguage = "bos" I don't get appropriate result.

```
package pckgTranslator;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/MyRestService/{wordToTranslate},{fromLanguage},{toLanguage}")
public class clsTranslate {
@GET
public String doGet(@PathParam("wordToTranslate") String wordToTranslate, 
        @PathParam("fromLanguage") String fromLanguage, @PathParam("toLanguage")  String toLanguage) 
        throws Exception{
    Translator translator = new Translator();
    return translator.getTranslation(wordToTranslate,fromLanguage, toLanguage);        
}
```

}

This is XML fajl which I try to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gloss>
    <word id="001">
        <eng>ball</eng>
        <bos>lopta</bos>
    </word>
    <word id="002">
        <eng>house</eng>
        <bos>kuca</bos>
    </word>
    <word id="003">
        <eng>game</eng>
        <bos>igra</bos>
    </word>
</gloss>
```

And this is the class which I'm using for parsing XML.

```
package pckgTranslator;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Translator {

String translation = null;

String getTranslation(String wordForTransl, String fromLanguage, String toLanguage)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

    //fromLanguage = "eng";
    //toLanguage = "bos";

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputStream is = Translator.class.getResourceAsStream("/resource/glossary.xml");
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(is));

    XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

    //XPathExpression expr = null; //xpath.compile("//word[eng='house']/bos/text()");
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//word['" + wordForTransl + "'='" + wordForTransl + "']/bos/text()");
    if (fromLanguage == "eng") {
        expr = xpath.compile("//word[eng='" + wordForTransl + "']/bos/text()");
    } else if (fromLanguage == "bos") {
        expr = xpath.compile("//word[bos='" + wordForTransl + "']/eng/text()");

    }

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        translation = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    }
    //return nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    if (translation != null) {
        return translation;
    } else {
        return "We are sorry, there is no translation for this word!";
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that something is wrong with the parameters fromLanguage and toLanguage, but I can't realize what exactly. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems you have hardcoded `fromLanguage` and `toLanguage` variables to `eng` and `bos` at the beginning of getTranslation() method. Remove these assignments and check.

Comment: I see another issue in @Path. Why do you have comma separated path params?

Comment: What is appropriate way to separate parameters? I couldn't find the another option.

Comment: Separate with `/` instead of `,`. Modified the answer.

Comment: please see the updated answer. If you need to pass multiple parameters, either use multiple `@PathParam` separated by `/` or use `@QueryParam`. After making this change of you still face issues, please log or print the input values i in `doGet()` method to understand what exactly you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you have hardcoded `fromLanguage` and `toLanguage` variables to `eng` and `bos` at the beginning of `getTranslation()` method. Due to this, the `fromLanguage` and 'toLangugae`values passed to`getTranslation()` method are lost.

Secondly, instead of separating `@PathParm` by `,` separate those by `/`. It will look like:

```
@Path("/MyRestService/{wordToTranslate}/{fromLanguage}/{toLanguage}")
@GET
public String doGet(@PathParam("wordToTranslate") String wordToTranslate, 
@PathParam("fromLanguage") String fromLanguage, @PathParam("toLanguage")  String toLanguage) throws Exception

Invocation: curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/MyRestService/x/y/z
```

Alternatively use `@QueryParam`. In that case your path would be:

```
@Path("/MyRestService")
public String doGet(@QueryParam("wordToTranslate") String wordToTranslate, 
@QueryParam("fromLanguage") String fromLanguage, @QueryParam("toLanguage")  String toLanguage) throws Exception

Invocation: curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/MyRestService?wordToTranslate=x&fromLanguage=y&toLanguage=z
```

Remove or comment the below lines in `getTranslation()` method:

```
fromLanguage = "eng";
toLanguage = "bos";
```

---

**Note:** **To fix your issue the above solution is sufficient**. However, to make you code better please see the below suggestions.
In addition to the above I see two more issues:

- You are storing translated value in `translation` instance variable. In case you are using the same Translator object (singleton instance) and the current translation fails, `getTranslation()` will return the previously translated value.
- Why are you initializing `expr` with the below?

```
   XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//word['" + wordForTransl + "'='" + wordForTransl + "']/bos/text()");
```

- Lastly, every time you are calling `getTranslation()` the XML is being parsed. Instead, parse it once in `init()` method and then use it in `getTranslation()` method.

I have modified your `Translator` class based on the above points:

```
package org.openapex.samples.misc.parse.xml;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ParseXMLAndTranslate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Translator translator = new Translator();
        translator.init();
        System.out.println(translator.getTranslation("house","eng", "bos"));
        System.out.println(translator.getTranslation("igra","bos", "eng"));
    }

    private static class Translator {
        //String translation = null;
        private Document doc;
        public void init() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream is = Translator.class.getResourceAsStream("/resource/glossary.xml");
            this.doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(is));
        }

        String getTranslation(String wordForTransl, String fromLanguage, String toLanguage)
                throws XPathExpressionException {
            //fromLanguage = "eng";
            //toLanguage = "bos";
            XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

            //XPathExpression expr = null; //xpath.compile("//word[eng='house']/bos/text()");
            //XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//word['" + wordForTransl + "'='" + wordForTransl + "']/bos/text()");
            XPathExpression expr = null;
            if (fromLanguage == "eng") {
                expr = xpath.compile("//word[eng='" + wordForTransl + "']/bos/text()");
            } else if (fromLanguage == "bos") {
                expr = xpath.compile("//word[bos='" + wordForTransl + "']/eng/text()");
            }

            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            String translation = null;
            /*for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                //System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
                translation = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            }*/
            if(nodes.getLength() > 0){
                translation = nodes.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
            //return nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            if (translation != null) {
                return translation;
            } else {
                return "We are sorry, there is no translation for this word!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
kuca
game
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help. 
I think that I understood your suggestions, but don't understand for what the "public class ParseXMLAndTranslate stands" class stands for. 
PS - I edited original class Translator, commented two lines fromLanguage and toLanguage, but the problem still persists.

Comment: `ParseXMLAndTranslate` class is to test your `Translator`. You may ignore this. Did you modify the separator `,` to `/` in @Path annotation? Also, move the `@Path` annotation to `doGet()` method from the class level. Did you print on console or log what values you are receiving in `doGet()` method?

Comment: Thanks for help and patiente.
I will try to implement it now. Sorry, I'm novice in Java.

Comment: @Adnan No problem. Please try to change the `@Path` declaration as suggested in the answer. If your issue is not resolved please let me know.

Comment: I deeply studied your code. I created completely new Java project in Netbeans (Java DESKTOP app) and it really great works. 
But, for some reason, the same code doesn't work when I try to implement REST service (via WEB app in Netbeans). Especially when I try to put annotations inside the clsTranslate class like this https://i.postimg.cc/qvqvkvKX/cls-Translate.png - in such case REST service is not available for testing in Glassfish console.
https://i.postimg.cc/50VJF4Xr/test-Web-Service.png

Comment: This is what I get when leave @Path annotation outside the class (the same code works great in desktop app):
https://i.postimg.cc/3N3D9QcS/testing-RESTfull-WS.png